# Cross Domain Widget Loading From Yii Framework

Tags: jquery, yii, widget, cross-domain

I am going to sell this widget for free for different websites. Check the below link for the widget.

All I want to do is write such a code so that this widget is loaded with cross domain from my hosted server to the client website without messing up the current DOM elements of the client website

I have done this so far by achieving through the following code

I have Yii Framework giving you the controller code and the view which is returned as partial and it is being placed correctly on the page. The only thing is the view which is being returned has its on javascript libraries which are not loading I assume on the page and getting $ Undefined error

Please try to help me on this.

Cross Domain Website which will place the following javascript code to its website

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Insane
 * Date: 6/27/14
 * Time: 1:24 AM
 */

?>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Web Widget Tutorial - Example 3 - Putting things together</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="header">Web Widget Tutorial</h1>
<h2>Example 4 - Putting things together</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {

        // Localize jQuery variable
        var jQuery;

        /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
        if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
            var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
            script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            script_tag.setAttribute("src",
                "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
            if (script_tag.readyState) {
                script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
                    if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                        scriptLoadHandler();
                    }
                };
            } else {
                script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
            }
            // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
            (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
        } else {
            // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
            jQuery = window.jQuery;
            main();
        }

        /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
        function scriptLoadHandler() {
            // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
            // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
            jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
            // Call our main function
            main();
        }

        /******** Our main function ********/
        function main() {
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                /******* Load HTML *******/
                var jsonp_url = "http://localhost/yiiframework/web/index.php/Ads/index/?callback=?";
                $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
                    $('#example-widget-container').html(data.html);// Till here it works fine load the html returned from yii framework
                });
            });
        }

    })(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
</script>
<div class="clearfix popup" id="example-widget-container"> </div>

</html>
```

This is Our hosted server Controller Code From YII Framework

```
<?php

class AdsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {

        //$this->layout = 'adswidget';
        $data = $this->renderPartial('index',null,true);
        $res = json_encode(array("html"=>$data));
        echo $_GET["callback"]."(".$res.")";

    }

    public function actionAdv()
    {
        $this->layout = 'adsdiv';
        $returnHtml  = $this->render('adv');
        return $returnHtml;
    }
    // Uncomment the following methods and override them if needed
    /*

}
```

The View Code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/style.css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/print.css" media="print" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />


    <div id="slideup" class="clear adheader" title="Ads"><div id="adheader" class="adheader" onmouseover="Tooltip('Ads-Click to see')"></div></div>

    <div id="slidedown" style="">
        <div class="clear popup_content">
            <hr style="margin: 5px 0;"/>

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
                        'type'=>'pills',
                        'placement'=>'left', // 'above', 'right', 'below' or 'left'
                        'tabs'=>array(
                            array('label'=>'Promos', 'content'=> '<div class=\'clear \'>

                                <div class=\'left two\'>
                                <div class=\'left one\'>
                                    <div class=\'banner\' id=\'zone4\'>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class=\'socialmedia\' >
                                                                <span class=\'st_facebook\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_twitter\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_linkedin\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_googleplus\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_pinterest\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_sharethis\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_email\'></span>
                                                                </div>
                                </div>  
                                </div>
                                <hr></div>', 'active'=>true),
                            array('label'=>'News', 'content'=>'<div class=\'clear \'>
                                                    <div class=\'left two\'>
                                                    <div class=\'left one\'>
                                                        <div class=\'banner52\' id=\'zone29\'>
                                                        </div>
                                                         <div class=\'socialmedia\' >
                                                                <span class=\'st_facebook\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_twitter\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_linkedin\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_googleplus\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_pinterest\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_sharethis\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_email\'></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                    </div>  
                                                    </div>
                                                    <hr></div>'),
                            array('label'=>'Deals', 'content'=>'<div id=\'deals\' class=\'clear \'>

                                                            <div class=\'left two\'>
                                                            <div class=\'left one\'>
                                                                <div class=\'banner\' id=\'zone\'>
                                                                </div>
                                                                 <div class=\'socialmedia\' >
                                                                <span class=\'st_facebook\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_twitter\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_linkedin\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_googleplus\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_pinterest\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_sharethis\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_email\'></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>  
                                                            </div>
                                                            <hr></div>'),
                            array('label'=>'Testimonial', 'content'=>'<div class=\'clear \'>
                                                                <div class=\'left two\'>
                                                                <div class=\'left one\'>
                                                                    <div class=\'banner\' id=\'zone17\'>

                                                                    </div>
                                                                 <div class=\'socialmedia\' >
                                                                <span class=\'st_facebook\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_twitter\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_linkedin\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_googleplus\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_pinterest\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_sharethis\'></span>
                                                                <span class=\'st_email\'></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                </div>  
                                                                </div>
                                                                <hr></div>'),

                        ),
                    )); ?>
            </div>
    </div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/oxtag/jquery.openxtag.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/oxtag/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/easyxdm/easyXDM.debug.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#slideup").click(function(){
            alert("adsasda");

            jQuery("#slidedown").slideToggle("fast",function(){
                    ("#slideup adheader").css='';
                }

            );
            if(jQuery('#slideup').text() == 'Latest Ads'){
                jQuery('#slideup').text('Latest Ads');
            }
            else
            {
                // $('#slideup').text('Latest Ads & Promos') ;

            }
        });
    });
</script>


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('#slideup').click(function() {
            var $lefty = jQuery(this).next();
            $lefty.animate({left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0});
        });

        $('#slidemarginleft button').click(function() {
            var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
            $marginLefty.animate({marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ? $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0});
        });



        jQuery('#slidewidthsome button').click(function() {
            var $some = jQuery(this).next(),
                someWidth = $some.outerWidth(),
                parentWidth = $some.parent().width();
            $some.animate({width: someWidth === parentWidth ? someWidth/2 : parentWidth - (parseInt($some.css('paddingLeft'),10) + parseInt($some.css('paddingRight'),10))});
        });
    });

</script>
<script>
    (function (jQuery) {


        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery.openxtag('init', {
                delivery: 'http://beta.sensibleticker.com/ads/www/delivery',
            });
            jQuery('.banner4').openxtag('iframe', 4, {
                width: 250,
                height: 250
            });
            jQuery('.banner52').openxtag('iframe', 52, {
                width: 250,
                height: 250
            });
            jQuery('.banner29').openxtag('iframe', 29, {
                width: 270,
                height: 300
            });
            jQuery('.banner').openxtag('iframe', 4, {
                width: 250,
                height: 250
            });
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery(function($) {
        jQuery('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
        jQuery('body').tooltip({"selector":"[data-toggle=tooltip]"});
        jQuery('#yw0').tab('show');
    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

When the view is loaded I believe its not returning the scripts along with it .I am attaching the firebug screenshot

[image: Cross Domain Web Widget Screen shot showing errors of jquery while loading]